# Proof for the bitwise XOR of two numbers to have Odd Number of set bits only when exactly one of them have odd number of bits?

Tags: algorithms, binary-operations

I was doing some Algorithms Contest Question ( OffCourse it is not live now), Where I encountered this amazing Pattern that Two Non Negative Numbers $A$ and  $B$  whose Exclusive XOR represented by $C=A \oplus B$ is going to have Odd Number of Set bits Only when exactly one of them A or B  have odd Number of Set bits for All other cases the C is going to have Even Number of Set Bits.. 
You can Take Any example of your wish A=2 and B=9 
where A has odd number of set bits and B has even set Bits without even xoring them I can say $A \oplus B$ is going to have odd number of bits.
I am not able to prove it in my head that why is it true? It will appreciated if someone can provide a more concrete proof..

Comment: Hint: If $\Delta$ is the XOR operator, and $b(x)$ is the number of bits in $x$ then show $b(x\Delta y)\equiv b(x)+b(y)\pmod 2.$

Comment: How do you come to this equation?

Comment: The total number of bits is $b(x)+b(y) - 2c$, where $c$ is the number of bits in common.

Comment: @Théophile Ya now I get it ... it was easier to deduce , LOL I should have tried harder..